# Expressjs GET request on javascript files as text/html

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, express

I have an application mostly in Angular, and I want to hook it up to Express to encrypt and send private API keys so they won't be stored plainly on the client.

My problem is that the browser reads statically served js files as text/html, which is causing my javascript to not load. You can see that the response is 200 and the file is there, just not being interpreted correctly.
[image: img]

index.html has many script requests like these

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/keys.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/public/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
```

Express routing code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

app.get('*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/views/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Anyone experienced with express - what is the proper way to serve static files with different MIME types? I eventually need to serve text/css types as well.

Comment: Try to change `/public/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js` to `/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js`.

Comment: Why would I do that when the browser is getting an ok 200 response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've configured your application to return `index.html` for every request:

```
app.get('*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/views/index.html'));
});
```

So express dutifully does just that, serves `index.html` for any and all requests, including the requests that you want to have return the `js` files via your `script` tags. For example, a request to `/public/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js` will actually return the file at `/public/views/index.html`.

A simple fix would be to just return `index.html` for a root request:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/views/index.html'));
});
```

In this way your `index.html` would be served at the root but your javascript assets could still be reached because you aren't serving `index.html` for every request.

Additionally, since you've told express that static assets can be found at `/public`, there's no need to include that directory when requesting them. So, your `script` includes should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice. I get it now. Although now i'm getting a 404 error for all assets, but you're spot on with the index.html getting served every time

Comment: @ShaharZ The 404 error is coming because you've included the public dir in the src attribute of your script tags. Since you've setup `express.static` using that dir, you should just use `/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js` as opposed to `/public/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js` in your script src.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your problem:

```
app.get('*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/views/index.html'));
});
```

You're sending index.html for literally *every* request.

Comment: Hmm that seems likely. But the thing is I want to send index.html on every request because it's a 1-page Angular app. index.html is a base for everything on the front end

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is not that `app.get('*', ...)` resolves for all requests (and overwrites responses from other middlewares), but that `express-static` is used incorrectly here.

In your example express-static does not resolve the request to a valid static-file in that directory and just invokes the next middleware / handler, which is in your case the app.get('*', ...). And that's why you see your index.html for every request.

#### Solutions

```html
- <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
+ <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Either you specify your resources in the HTML without the prefix `/public`,

```js
- app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
+ app.use('/public', express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

Or you adjust your express routing to handle the path prefix.